# tomcat7-maven-plugin log4j: no appender could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina)

Tags: xml, spring, tomcat, logging, log4j

I'm unable to initialize the log4j catalina log appender - do you know what I'm missing? I know that it's a basic issue, but I'm stuck on this. I added a org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender definition for the catalina logger, but no luck.

---

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina)
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

---

From what I can tell, I'm initialize the log4j system in the log4j.xml using  - what am I doing wrong? Again, I know it's a basic issue. This is my `/src/main/resources/log4j.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" name="stdout">
        <layout class="com.us.platform.thing.log.SyslogPatternLayout">
            <param value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %t %-5p %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="com.us.platform.thing.log.filter.DynamicLevelFilter">
            <param name="loggingDataBridgeClass" value="com.us.platform.thing.configuration.impl.ThingLoggingDataBridge" />
            <param name="useJmx" value="true" />
            <param name="baseLogLevelName" value="thing.logging.baselevel.core" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender" name="syslog">
        <param value="LOCAL4" name="facility"/>
        <param value="localhost" name="SyslogHost"/>
        <layout class="com.us.platform.thing.log.SyslogPatternLayout">
            <param value="{%t} %N{loggingFeature}|%N{loggingComponent} [%D] - %p %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="com.us.platform.thing.log.filter.DynamicLevelFilter">
            <param name="loggingDataBridgeClass" value="com.us.platform.thing.configuration.impl.ThingLoggingDataBridge" />
            <param name="useJmx" value="true" />
            <param name="baseLogLevelName" value="thing.logging.baselevel.core" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
        <appender class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender" name="catalina">
        <param value="LOCAL1" name="facility"/>
        <param value="localhost" name="SyslogHost"/>
        <layout class="com.us.platform.thing.log.SyslogPatternLayout">
            <param value="{%t} %-5p %c - %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0">
        <!-- Warn level is necessary or passwords are sent to logs. -->
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.mchange.v2">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
        <appender-ref ref="catalina"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This is the configuration for the tomcat7-maven-plugin, I know that it's huge, and I apologize for the amount of configuration that was required:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat7-maven-plugin-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <serverXml>${project.build.directory}/thing.tomcat.hosted.core/tomcat-core/conf/server.xml</serverXml>
        <tomcatWebXml>${project.build.directory}/thing.tomcat.hosted.core/tomcat-core/conf/web.xml</tomcatWebXml>
        <systemProperties>
            <JAVA_OPTS>-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</JAVA_OPTS>
            <com.sun.management.jmxremote.port>8004</com.sun.management.jmxremote.port>
            <com.sun.management.jmxremote>true</com.sun.management.jmxremote>
            <com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl>false</com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl>
            <com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate>false</com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate>
            <org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE>com.us.platform.thing.tomcat.startup.TomcatPropertySource</org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE>
            <project.version>${project.version}</project.version>
            <project.basedir>${project.basedir}</project.basedir>
        </systemProperties>
        <skip>${skipTomcat}</skip>
    <additionalClasspathDirs>
        <additionalClasspathDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathDir>
    </additionalClasspathDirs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <skip>${skipTomcat}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-tomcat</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skipTomcat}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Logging works properly when I manually specify where the log4j.xml file is.

```
$ mvn tomcat7:run -DskipTomcat=false -Dlog4j.configuration=file:src/main/resources/log4j.xml
```

---

Does anything obvious stick out?

Comment: See my answer belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the log4j.properties or XML to the systemProperties section:

Like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <port>8080</port>
        <path>/</path>
        <systemProperties>
            <log4j.configuration>file:src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <port>8080</port>
        <path>/</path>
        <systemProperties>
            <log4j.configurationFile>file:src/main/resources/log4j.xml</log4j.configurationFile>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```